# SharePoint Online - user input for approval workflows

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I have searched the net and also on here and cannot find the solution to this. I am setting up a List on SharePoint which would be an Induction Pack for new users.

The new user would add and Item to the List, three of the columns on this list would be an email address of someone in our company. What I am trying to do is use these three email addresses to set up a serial workflow so that the 1st column is the 1st approver, 2nd is 2nd approver and 3rd is 3rd (final) approver.

I know how to set up workflows OOTB and on designer for the whole list, but have not worked out how to make it work this way where it relies on user input.

Comment: Do it through MS Flow might easier and better in terms of use experience.  Here is a tutorial http://www.sharepointing.co.uk/2017/07/02/two-stage-approval-process-using-ms-flow/

Comment: thank you I will dl MS flow and try this out and get back to you, we used to use InfoPath but it doesn't seem to be compatible with sharepoint online

Comment: @SharePointer this worked very well, thanks a lot for the help, first time using this site so not sure how to give you positive ratings but many many thanks